# Difference of days between two dates in React.JS using moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, calculator, difference

I made a function which calculates difference between two dates, but i dont know how to take(?) data to it using inputs. I also tried to **return diffInDays;** and instead of that use **this.setState({ diffInDays: diffInDays })**. I've tried many combinations but none of them gave me the right result.

```
calculate(dateFrom, dateTo) {
    if (!dateFrom || !dateTo) {
       return null;
    }
    const arrival = moment(dateFrom);
    const departure = moment(dateTo);
    if (arrival.isAfter(departure)) {
       return null;
    }
      const diffInDays = departure
      .endOf('day')
      .diff(arrival.startOf('day'), 'days');
    
      return diffInDays;
}
```

those are the inputs I created:

- this one is for the beginning

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="dateFrom">Date From: </label>
  <input
    type="date"
    className="form-control"
    id="dateFrom"
    onChange={this.onChangeDateFrom}
    value={this.state.dateFrom}
    name="dateFrom"
   />
</div>
```

- and this one is for the end

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="dateTo">Date to: </label>
    <input
    type="date"
    className="form-control"
    id="dateTo"
    onChange={this.onChangeDateTo}
    value={this.state.dateTo}
    name="dateTo"
    />
</div>
```

- and this is the one where I want to see the difference

```
<div className="form-group">
   <label htmlFor="daysDiff">Days Difference: </label>
   <input
   type="number"
   className="form-control"
   id="daysDiff"
   required
   value={this.state.daysDiff}
   name="daysDiff"
   readOnly
   />
</div>
```

Picking the dates works fine. They also save in the MongoDB, the problem appears only with the difference of days.

Answer (score 0):

You should use
`departure.diff(arrival)`
and for getting only day difference
`departure.diff(arrival,'days')`

Comment: One of the combinations I wrote, it calculates the number of days but it doesn't want to show it in the input https://i.imgur.com/c4ZQzkw.png   you can see the console.log on the right

Comment: If you want to show this difference in input field, you need to set this difference in your daysDiff state on each time you change your date fields.

Comment: `const [daysDiff,setDateDiff] = useState();` and inside calculate function you should use `setDateDiff(diffInDays);`

Comment: I tried to use your code but, i dont know where to put the const [daysDiff,setDateDiff] = useState(); i read that it's something about react hooks but i've never used them. 
here's my code of this component: https://pastebin.com/vLJFxjeD

Comment: I saw your code. You should put `const [daysDiff,setDateDiff] = useState();` before your this.state block.And remove daysDiff from this.state

Comment: When i added it in 28th line, it says  "Line 57:3:  'setDateDiff' is not defined  no-undef", it's same error when i added it in the 140th line